# Re-direct all traffic to error page using IIS Manager 2008?

Tags: iis

Our database has just crashed so need to take down IIS - is there anyway to just have a catch all, so whatever page a user visits will display an error message, as opposed to just stopping the service and having the 'Unable to connect' error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stick a file called app_offline.htm in the root of your web application, IIS will shut-down the application, unload the application domain from the server, and stop processing any new incoming requests for that application.

It will then simply return the contents of the app_offline.htm file to anyone making requests to your application giving you the chance to send back an informative message.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you :) (edit) nope, unfortunately a file called app_offline.htm in /wwwroot/ has no effect :(

Comment: @Nick This should not go in wwwroot, it need to go in the root of your application. So if you virtual directory for application 'test app' is at 'c:\prod\test app' then that is where the app_offline.htm file should be placed.